# DocsList to DriveApp: Cannot find function addFile in object: Line 165

Tags: google-apps-script

I know I am not alone out there in having some issues with Google's deprecation of `DocsList` in favor of `DriveApp`. I have replaced all references to `DocList` with `DriveApp` in my code.

I have a spreadsheet containing variables that used to merge nicely with a Google Docs template, effectively a mailmerge.

Here are the declared variables:

```
var myDataSheet, myVariablesSheet;
var rowId, maxRows, maxRowsOverride;
var templateDocId;
var timeZone, timestamp, dateline;
var newFolder, newFolderId, collectionDate, collectionName,appendTimestamp;
var newDocNameBase, newDocNameSuffixCol, newDocName, newDoc, newDocId;
var fieldColRow, fieldArr, colArr;
```

When I run the script, I am returning an error identified at line 165 of my code. The error states:

> TypeError: Cannot find function addFile in object Copy of Letter of
>   Rep Template. (line 165, file "Mail Merge")

Line 165 reads:

```
DriveApp.getFileById(newDocId).addFile(DriveApp.getFolderByName(newFolderId));
```

Oddly, (at least to me) when I run the script I get a single outputted merged document, but never more than one.

I suspect that I am dealing with a failing loop of some kind, and an issue with my file naming and my destination folder, but I cannot get past where I am... any insight, help or just a straight fix greatly appreciated.

Comment: hasnt been properly changed. for example you call addFile on a file object

Comment: Do you need more information to give me more guidance?

Answer (score 0):

The `getFolderByName()` method returns a **Folder Iterator**.  In other words, it returns an "object" that can have multiple elements in it.  Even though you may only have one folder with a given name, you still need to use a loop to access the one folder.

[Google Documentation - Folder Iterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder-iterator)

You are not going to be able to chain all the methods together that you have in that one line of code giving you the error.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm afraid I'm no coder, so you may have to unpack your response for me a little more...would it help if I posted the entire script? Or is there a more efficient method.

Comment: There is example code at the link in the answer.  You'll need to do some work on learning how to program in JavaScript also.

Answer (score 0):

I saw a few mistakes with your code.

1. `DriveApp.getFolderByName(String)` looks for folders with the given name, and returns multiple folders. You seemed to have passed in the folder's id. A folder's id and its name are different. You can create a folder named "MyFolder", and another folder called "MyFolder". Their names will be the same, but their id's will be unique.
2. You're calling `File.addFile(Folder);`, which doesn't exist. That's why you're getting that error. You should switch it around and use `Folder.addFile(File)` instead. Here's the fixed code:

`DriveApp.getFolderById(newDocId).addFile(DriveApp.getFileById(newDocId));`

This question is a bit old but I hope I could help :)